# Creating Offline Bot using Oryzer Studio (OSCOVA) and Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, chatbot

I am building an app using Xamarin android, and I have used Oryzer studio to built my chatbot. How can I import the workspace to my apps for further development?

It works when importing the workspace to a Console app (using bot.ImportWorkspace(@"my path.west")) but not in android apps. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit late, I believe you should save the Workspace file as a resource and use the `LoadFromString` method by reading the content of the resource as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sorry that I am a new learner on both Xamarin android and chatbot. Can you elaborate more on it?  After I tried added the workspace (.west file) into the Resources file, an error "invalid file path" appeared. Am I incorrectly adding the workspace in Xamarin android? In the file properties, I set the Build Action to "Android Resources"